# npm install is raising this error "npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall script."

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-sass

I am to work on this SPFx web part @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-enhanced-list-formatting . so i downloaded the files, then i tried to run `npm install`.. but i got this error:-

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 14.17.0 (x64) and npm.

C:\Windows\System32>cd C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting

C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting>npm install

> node-sass@4.12.0 install C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.12.0/win32-x64-83_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.12.0/win32-x64-83_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\react-enhanced-list-formatting\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.17.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python39\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:319:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\react-enhanced-list-formatting\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN @voitanos/jest-preset-spfx-react16@1.3.2 requires a peer of jest@^24.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.1 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN gulp-stylelint@11.0.0 requires a peer of stylelint@^10.1.0 || ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-jest@24.0.2 requires a peer of jest@>=24 <25 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-enhanced-list-formatting@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN react-enhanced-list-formatting@0.0.1 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-12T18_25_56_343Z-debug.log
```

any advice ?